# I am trying to querymongodb collection to get one particular id field -

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, mongoid

I am trying to get _id from last updated("timeSliceStart") row which has matching "EmployeeName"

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(EmployeeName).sort(new BasicDBObject("timeSliceStart", -1)).limit(1);
 while(cursor.hasNext()) {
            String result = cursor.next().get("id"); }
```

Data in Mongo DB::

`{
    "_id" : {
        "employeeId" : "1234567890",
        "@objectName" : "FeedMetadata"
    },
    "school" : false,
    "college" : null,
    "errorCount" : 0,
    "errors" : [],
    "EmployeeName" : "Peter"
}`

The result that is getting printed is :
`{ "employeeId" : "1234567890" , "@objectName" : "FeedMetadata"}`

I want just the employeeId from _id, I tried `_id.employeeId ;`, but it returned `null`.
Is there a way to display only the employeeId?

My Java program -

```
  BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("EmployeeName", empName);
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(whereQuery).sort(new BasicDBObject("lastUpdate", -1)).limit(1);
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        String result = cursor.next().get("_id").toString();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: Could you write some code of employee document class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the while loop like this:

```
while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    String result = ((HashMap)((BasicDBObject)(cursor.next().get("_id")))).get("employeeId");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```