# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve one particular field(`"Versions.id"`) from mongo using java

Mongo query - `db.getCollection('SettlementInstance').find({"_id.timeSlice" : [2018,1,1], "_id.type" : "TRANSMISSION"})`

This is the data stored in mongo collection. I want to retrieve  `"id" : "3d8a3b31-aaa0-4c2e-82b3-5eaaa80d80e1"` using java

```
   {
            "_id" : {
                "timeSlice" : [ 
                    2018, 
                    1, 
                    1
                ],
                "type" : "TRANSMISSION",
                "@objectName" : "SettlementInstance"
            },
            "Versions" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "3d8a3b31-aaa0-4c2e-82b3-5eaaa80d80e1",
                    "status" : "ACTIVE",
                    "version" : NumberLong(11447)
                }
            ]
        }
```

The Java program I was trying to retrieve the "id" field under "Versions" object, my code gives an exception.

```
String feedName = "ServicePointInputAdapter";
            Mongo mongo = new Mongo(host);
            DB db = mongo.getDB(("dbname"));
            DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("SettlementInstance");
            BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
            whereQuery.put("_id.type", "TRANSMISSION");
            whereQuery.put("_id.timeSlice", Arrays.asList(2018,1,1));
            DBCursor cursor = collection.find(whereQuery);
            try {
                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    DBObject Features = cursor.next();
                    BasicDBList features = (BasicDBList) Features.get("Versions");
                    BasicDBObject[] featuresArr = features.toArray(new BasicDBObject[0]);
                    for (BasicDBObject dbobj : featuresArr) {
        *****                BasicDBObject si_id = (BasicDBObject) dbobj.get("id"); ***** //Getting error in the line }
                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I am getting exception such as -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject.
```

Could some one help me resolve the issue and retrieve the "Versions.id" field from the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error clearly says that you are trying to cast a `java.lang.String` to `com.mongodb.BasicDBObject` which is throwing `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Change the line of code as below (as BasicDBObject implements HashMap):

```
for (BasicDBObject dbobj : featuresArr) {
    String id = (String)((HashMap)dbobj).get("id");
    System.out.println(id);
}
```

Comment: I already tried as String and tried to print the si_id - The program printed whole part under Versions such as - { "id" : "3d8a3b31-aaa0-4c2e-82b3-5eaaa80d80e1" , "status" : "ACTIVE" , "version" : 11447}

I specifically just want the "id" field to be printed.

Comment: Typecast the BasicDBObject to HashMap and get id out of it.

Comment: @janopan Thanks for marking the answer as correct. Also, can you please upvote it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49699907/i-am-trying-to-querymongodb-collection-to-get-one-particular-id-field
Can you try to answer this on mongoid field (_id). I just want to get/print  "_id.employeeId" field only

Answer (score 0):

This get() method only returns the value. So it was a string when you do this

```
dbobj.get("id")
```

You should pass the field name as the parameter and you will get the value. So change this line like below

```
BasicDBObject si_id = (BasicDBObject) dbobj.get("id");

to 
String dbObjectId = dbobj.get("id");
```

Comment: I already tried as String and tried to print the si_id - The program printed whole part under Versions such as - { "id" : "3d8a3b31-aaa0-4c2e-82b3-5eaaa80d80e1" , "status" : "ACTIVE" , "version" : 11447} I specifically just want the "id" field to be printed

Comment: have you tried using only this DBObject Features = cursor.next(); in hasNext() loop?. You can directly get the results there.